# displaying the xml content with html tags

Tags: java, html, xml

I have some information stored in an xml file. I need to display the data in html format and also a few designs which include CSS. How can I do this?

Comment: I don’t really understand what you’re asking. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how much work you want to do. You could always parse the [XML using Java](http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html) to create the HTML output, or you could also use [XSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XSLT).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css directly to your xml file with xml-stylesheet processing instruction. For examle, xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<root>
  <value>value 1</value>
  <value>value 2</value>
</root>
```

and style.css:

```
root {
  background-color: yellow;
}
value {
  display: block;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

For more complex processing you can use XSLT.